# Tricks to implement a function timeout

Tags: c++, timeout

I am developing algorithms that have a running-time hard to predict (they are highly input-dependent) and for some users the running-time needs to remain bounded. So I need to enhance the code with a timeout mechanism.

It is thinkable to launch the algorithm in a separate thread and wait for completion, for example with a timed mutex, and abort if necessary. But a problem is that abortion of the algorithm will stop it in an arbitrary state, possibly losing partial results already obtained, but - more problematically - leaving the objects that take part to the processing in an invalid state.

Can you advise about the methods used in practice ? How to interrupt processing ? How to make sure that interruption will not take further time ? How to make sure that the system returns to a stable state ? How to avoid busy waiting and other forms of overhead ?

I am just in a concept stage, nothing programmed so far. Thinking of soft methods (letting the code time itself) vs. hard ones (external interruption).

Comment: You don't need a separate thread.  You just need the routine to track how long it has been running, and if the duration exceeds the duration bound, then return from the routine.  Do whatever cleanup is necessary, and if partial results can be returned then return them.

Comment: design code such that you can interrupt it at any point from the start. Perhaps not in every single iteration, but lets say after 10 iterations you check some `should_i_continue` flag. If you plan for this from the start, then conceptually, letting it run until finished or until some timeout elapsed is almost the same

Comment: @Eljay: ok, that's what I call a "soft" method. There is a "but": if you want to be accurate, you need to read time often enough, and that causes overhead. My code is made of several nested loops, and all of them run for an unknown number of iterations. Choosing where to measure time is uneasy.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: yep. See my comment to Eljay. Also, stepping out of complex nested loops may require a lot of care for proper handling.

Comment: there is no magic solution. Decide where to put "interruption points" (points in time / code where you check if you need to continue to run). More of them means more overhead, less of them means less accuracy. Btw this question is too broad and likely to be closed because it needs more focus

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: yes, I understand it.

Comment: eg " Also, stepping out of complex nested loops may require a lot of care for proper handling" is unclear. Stepping out of nested loops is done via `return`, and proper handling is RAII. I dont see the issue.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: cleanup may require different actions depending where you interrupt from.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes. This problem has a solution in c++, its called RAII. Cleanup is done in destructors.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: thanks, I will consider this.

Comment: you are referring to problems that only you know. I can imagine some issues to be encountered, but what your issue is I cannot know. Returning from a nested loop and doing proper clean up is generally not a problem. If you have encountered one you should try to be more specific, perhaps show some code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: sorry, but the code is huge. I essentially wanted to know if there are specific techniques, but it seems that not.

Comment: RAII *is* the technique that is exactly to make sure that no matter at which point you exit from a function the proper clean up is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the code in its own process, then on most modern operating systems, when the process gets killed, the kernel will automatically and reliably clean up the entire process. However, this will cause all intermediate results to get lost, unless the killed process regularily reported its intermediate results using some form of [interprocess communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Also, the process would require its own copy of the data, except for the data that is strictly read-only. The read-only data could be shared by both processes.

However, if you can trust the code that you are running to check a shared flag in sufficiently regular intervals, and to gracefully terminate in a time-bounded manner if that flag is set, then it should not be necessary to run that code in a separate process and to kill it. In the case of a graceful termination, the code should be designed in such a way that it reports its last set of valid intermediate results to the caller before terminating.

Comment: The issue of cleaning is not related to the kernel but to my own data structures, which evolve with processing and could be left in an intermediate state. The other issue is the "sufficiently regular intervals" which is uneasy to achieve: too frequently causes overhead, too sparsely can cause failure to be on time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: If you cannot trust the algorithm to gracefully terminate in a time-bounded manner, then I'm afraid that you will have to run it in its own process and kill it on timeout. In that case, the process will require its own copy of the data, except for the data that is strictly read-only. Note that I have edited my answer to add this information.